# PascalScript in freepascal

Tags: freepascal, pascalscript

Is there any units or libraries or dlls for PascalScript in freepascal to call?

If so, what file do I need?And how can I let the program (which is prepared to run) could call some functions in other unit?

If not,is there any succedaneum like PascalScript?

Comment: Afaik you need to register functions with pascalscript in order to be able to call them.  Also, pascalscript needs to match the calling conventions exactly, and this (ffi-like) code is a bit of a black art.

Comment: The wiki article https://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Pascal_Script_Examples might be helpful